# UI.ImageView in TideSDK?

Tags: tidesdk

A few years back I have been using Titanium Desktop to make an app for Mac. Having been satisfied I came back recently to it for another project, but apparently Titanium Desktop is now TideSDK.

Looking at the reference it seems that a lot of stuff has disappeared, I was mostly expecting more elements in UI, like ScrollView, ImageView and such.

Did they simply vanish from this new release or is it just not fully documented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I need to make clear that TideSDK is not Titanium Desktop. While it began on legacy code, more than 1 million lines changes of code have been committed and the SDK has been in existence for almost a year now. You will find a different namespace but API compatibility.

The code base is quite different and has been undergoing major restructuring and improvements. That said, for the end user, it is just as friendly to use. We  don't like to go back to discuss the past since we have contributed a body of code that allows developers to run TideSDK on today's modern operating systems. This was only the result of substantial efforts and the continued development of TideSDK by its contributors. If you experience any issues, please file them with on our issue tracker on github.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for clearing some details up ! 
But still, my question is really if all the UI components (like ScrollView, ImageView, etc) that were in Titanium Desktop, are available or not in TideSDK ?

Comment: @Gabor, you seem to be confused with mobile that relied on these APIs to translate to native widgets. The APIs you make reference to are not currently within the scope of TideSDK - nor were part of any legacy code we inherited. Mital is saying that underneath, TideSDK runs on different code base than the past and that we are compatible with the legacy APIs except for namespace. There is no UI code that has somehow fallen away. TideSDK is focused on UI elements that include native windows, system tray, menus etc and currently the rest is up to you.

Comment: Sorry to have bothered you guys, I actually just remembered that that app was for iPad and not Mac, so it was indeed the mobile API that I remembered !